# View Holder pattern not working

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have implemented a custom listview in which I have two textviews and checkbox. These are encapsulated into a linear layout on whoms click I check/uncheck the checkbox. The problem I am facing is that when I click the linear layout, it checks the checkbox but it also checks other checkboxes on a fixed pattern i.e every 7-8 rows. I read many problems regarding it and found out that implementing a view holder would solve the problem but that's also not working for me. Following is my code:

**CustomListAdapter:**

```
public class ContactsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private List<ContactInfo> contacts;
    private List<ContactInfo> selectedContacts;

    public ContactsListAdapter(Context context, List<ContactInfo> contacts) {
        this.context = context;
        this.contacts = contacts;
        selectedContacts = new ArrayList<ContactInfo>();
    }

    public List<ContactInfo> getSelectedContacts() {
        return selectedContacts;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return contacts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return contacts.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Long.parseLong(contacts.get(position).id);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_row_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.view = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llContactRow);
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvContactName);
            holder.number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvContactNumber);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbMultipleSelect);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.name.setText(contacts.get(position).name);
        holder.number.setText(contacts.get(position).number);
        holder.view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ContactInfo contact = new ContactInfo();
                contact.id = contacts.get(position).id;
                contact.name = contacts.get(position).name;
                contact.number = contacts.get(position).number;
                holder.checkbox.setChecked(!holder.checkbox.isChecked());
                if(holder.checkbox.isChecked()) {
                    selectedContacts.add(contact);
                } else {
                    selectedContacts.remove(contact);
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        LinearLayout view;
        CheckBox checkbox;
        TextView name;
        TextView number;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

**EDIT:**
After doing what @vinitius asked me to do the problem was resolved but the checks are disappearing when I scroll the list. Here is my new `getView()`:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_row_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.view = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llContactRow);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvContactName);
        holder.number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvContactNumber);
        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbMultipleSelect);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.name.setText(contacts.get(position).name);
    holder.number.setText(contacts.get(position).number);
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(selectedContacts.contains(contacts.get(position)));
    holder.view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ContactInfo contact = new ContactInfo();
            contact.id = contacts.get(position).id;
            contact.name = contacts.get(position).name;
            contact.number = contacts.get(position).number;
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(!holder.checkbox.isChecked());
            if(holder.checkbox.isChecked()) {
                selectedContacts.add(contact);
            } else {
                selectedContacts.remove(contact);
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not showing your content in your `getView()`. Do the following:

```
  @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //remove the other stuff. You don't want to create new instances here, otherwise you won't be able to remove them later 
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(!holder.checkbox.isChecked());
            if(holder.checkbox.isChecked()) {
                selectedContacts.add(contact.get(position));
            } else {
                selectedContacts.remove(contact.get(position));
            }
        }
```

And do it before you set `OnClickListener` for your `LinearLayout`:

```
holder.checkbox.setChecked(selectedContacts.contains(contacts.get(position)));
```

And if you want the same behaviour when hitting the `CheckBox`, just add to your `CheckBox` xml:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

So the `linearLayout` can intercept it

Comment: The problem persists.

Comment: Actually it worked. But the problem is after some time, the checks disappear (when I scrolled the listview).

Comment: How did you do it? Can you update? It works fine for me

Comment: Well actually I just missed your last line of the answer. When I added that to my code, it worked. Then I scrolled and the checks disappeared.

Comment: No, the checks are disappearing. Why is that happening?

Comment: Please, update your question with the edited code for checking

Comment: Ok,just remember: you're doing it when you click the `linearLayout`, so if you hit the `checkBox` itself it will not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69921/discussion-between-mohammad-areeb-siddiqui-and-vinitius).

Answer (score 1):

your issue is that you need to set holder.checkbox.setChecked() to a value underneath the line:

```
    holder.number.setText(contacts.get(position).number);
```

Currently you are changing the value of it when it is checked but you need to set the value when your getview method is called otherwise it will just keep whatever value it had before.

It would probably be best if you had a 'selected' value in your contactinfo rather than managing a new list. This way you could do something like:

```
holder.checkbox.setChecked(contacts.get(position).isSelected);
```

Comment: But I want it to be checked only when user clicks on the linear layout

Comment: Why would it be best?

Comment: The issue is that the checkbox is not being reset. Maybe you just want to ensure that setChecked is set to false just so that it is reset and only checked after click.

Comment: You are managing another array unnecessarily. It would be easier to track your data rather than adding/removing from another array.

Comment: You mean to say that add another boolean into the ContactInfo class which will hold the value if the contact is selected or not. This is not a good idea to add a non-related boolean in a class.

Comment: oh ok. I don't know much about your program and if this contactinfo class was just for this purpose only. either way, the problem with your code was related to the checkbox keeping it's old value after it has been checked because it was not reset.